What happens if the block driver returns I/O error when handling addr fault for swap
If a block device was attached as a swap space, there can now be virtual addresses which require operation from the block driver to be read/written.
When such address is accessed, a page fault is raised, and the kernel then requests the corresponding blockdevice driver to read or write. But block device can return input/output error. So I have few interconnected questions:

What happens if the block driver returns I/O Error when the kernel is handling an address fault for the swap? Will it be propagated as a "segmentation fault" error or a "bus error"?
What happens if such error occurs when the swapped address is accessed from kernel mode (not user)? Will it be the same as with "bus error" i.e an Oops?
Is page fault handler considered an atomic context i.e is it possible to sleep while handling an address fault? How far things can go to handle a page fault (i.e can the addr's data be on a network, or even provided by a userspace program?)
Does the block driver have a way to know if it is handling such an important operation and not just a normal read/write from usermode?


See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870696/simulate-a-faulty-block-device-with-read-errors for some ways that you could test this for yourself.
